# How to move focus to another div after choosing an option in a listbox?

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

I have a side panel with a list of options. Tabbing will move from one option to the other. After choosing one of the options, another div will appear (#focushere) and focus should be on that div. However, I can't get it to work even when using focus. 
Is there a way to remove focus on the selected option in the listbox?
I am using Voiceover and jaws.

```js
$(".option").on("click", function() {
  $("#focushere").focus();
});
```

```css
#focushere {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.option {
  border:1px solid #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="listbox">
  <div class="option" role="option">test 1</div>
  <div class="option" role="option">test 2</div>
  <div class="option" role="option">test 3</div>
</div>

<div id="focushere">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work well enough on a JS Fiddle.

I just had to add `tabindex` attributes on your `div` elements and assign attributes to the `:focus` selector in the CSS.

```
:focus {border: 3px solid red;}

<div role="listbox">
  <div class="option" role="option" tabindex="0">test 1</div>
  <div class="option" role="option" tabindex="0">test 2</div>
  <div class="option" role="option" tabindex="0">test 3</div>
</div>

<div id="focushere" tabindex="0"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xyzcaqmk/11/

Answer (score 0):

Use tabindex=“-1” This makes the div focusable but not tabbable.